# How can I check the last time someone commited code in my git repo

Tags: git, github

How can I check the last time someone commited code in my git repo.

I need a quick and easy way to see the last time my developers did a commit to my git repo, I know I can use the following to see the number of commits but I need the date/time of the last commit per developer

```
git pull  -v; git shortlog -s -n -e
```

Please help me.. I need a east way to find out the last time each of my developers did a commit.

shortlog is great but I also need the last time/date that each developer did a commit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started.  It displays the commit time and then the summary on the next line.

```
git shortlog -sne |awk '{print $1,$2,$3,system("git log -n1 --format=%cd --author=" $2)}'
```

It looks terrible and includes an extra 0 at the end, but it does provide you what you asked for.